# Вывести случайное кол-во div из списка

Tags: javascript

В файле есть n количество `div` с классом `item-1, item-2, ...`. Как случайно вывести несколько элементов из общего пула?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае Вам необходимо использовать `js` или `jqeury`

Вот пример на `jquery`

```js
        $(function() {
            var n = 5, // количество сколько надо вывести div
            divs = $('div[class*="item"]').get(); // Получаем все div класс которых содержит item
            for ( ; n--; )  {
                $(divs.splice(Math.random()*divs.length|0,1)).prependTo('#SelectedDivs').show();
            }
        });
```

```css
        #SelectedDivs div {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="SelectedDivs">
    <div class="item-1">Текст 1</div>
    <div class="item-2">Текст 2</div>
    <div class="item-3">Текст 3</div>
    <div class="item-4">Текст 4</div>
    <div class="item-5">Текст 5</div>
    <div class="item-6">Текст 6</div>
    <div class="item-7">Текст 7</div>
    <div class="item-8">Текст 8</div>
    <div class="item-9">Текст 9</div>
    <div class="item-10">Текст 10</div>
    <div class="item-11">Текст 11</div>
    <div class="item-12">Текст 12</div>
    <div class="item-13">Текст 13</div>
    <div class="item-14">Текст 14</div>
    <div class="item-15">Текст 15</div>
</div>
```